# Moved images to another folder - need help with htaccess rewrite rule for png

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, png

I had to move my image folder. 
Before it was `example.com/shoplogo/(name*).png` now its `example.com/shop-logo/(name*).png` just stuck with the rewrite rule :-(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the visible links to your images remain the same and point to the old location: `shoplogo` and you need to internally rewrite the request to the correct location (ie. `shop-logo`) so that they still work.

Then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the root of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shoplogo/([^/]+\.png)$ /shop-logo/$1 [L]
```

`$1` is a backreference to the captured filename.

Comment: thanks that worked, almost had it but stupid me... THANKS

Comment: You're welcome - glad it worked. In the future, if you include the code you have tried in your question then we can maybe just correct and explain why the original code didn't work. As with many things (in `.htaccess`), there are many ways to write essentially the same thing.